# Read data from mysql php jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I need to read data from my web page with jquery + ajax

This is my function:

```
public function getvalueshahr()
{
if($_POST['ostan']!=0){
$db=  JFactory::getDbo();
$query=$db->getQuery(TRUE);
$query->select('id,title')->from('#__categories')->
where($db->quoteName('parent_id').'='.$db->quote($_POST['ostan']));
$db->setQuery($query);
$res=$db->loadObjectList();
echo $db->getErrorMsg();
echo json_encode($res);}
}
```

I can read data with c# like this:

[image]

But my ajax method is not working. Here is the method:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "www.mysite.net/index.php?task=shahrestan.getvalueshahr",
  data: "{ostan=77}",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (result)
  {
    var d = $.parseJSON(result);
    $.each(d, function (i, field)
  {
    $("#output").append("id: " + field.id + " title: " +  
    field.title+"br/>"); 
  });
  },
    error: function (e)
  {
    alert("error:" + e.responseText);
  }
 });
```

The method returns nothing.

Comment: You should really learn how to write good code, your code looks very messy and is hard to read.

Comment: thanks any book or ebook

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you send a wrong data to the server. You have to rewrite part of your code like this:

```
data: {ostan: 77},
```

or

```
data: "ostan=77",
```

The second problem is you get a result as a json object on the success method, but you try to parse it again to the json object. So remove this line from your code:

```
var d = $.parseJSON(result);
```

Finally your ajax function should looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "www.mysite.net/index.php?task=shahrestan.getvalueshahr",
  data: {ostan: 77},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (result)
  {
    $.each(result, function (i, field)
  {
    $("#output").append("id: " + field.id + " title: " +  
    field.title+"br/>"); 
  });
  },
    error: function (e)
  {
    alert("error:" + e.responseText);
  }
 });
```

Comment: thanks, it returns an error message and   e.responseText is empty how can i get  error details

Comment: Add a "complete" method to your ajax to get all data about server error. You have to write like this example:

complete: function (res) {
    console.log(res);
}

Run your codes on the chrome browser, than from the console copy and paste the output result please

Answer (score 2):

You're sending a string instead of an object in your ajax-request. Try changing :

```
data: "{ostan=77}"
```

to

```
data: { ostan: 77 }
```

And you should set the content type before echoing the results in PHP:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($res);
```

Now you don't need `$.parseJSON` in the JS-code. You will get a json-object straight away.

Comment: thanks, it returns an error message and e.responseText is empty how can i get error details

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(e)` instead of `alert(e.responteText)` when catching the error? Use your browsers console to see the output. Here's how to open it in different browsers: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading data from you mysql-database you eventually have to convert these data because it is not stored as utf-8 converted. This piece of code convert given object to UTF-8: `mb_convert_encoding(database-entry,'UTF-8');`